# Keras prompts Error: (Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have 4 dimensions)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Here's my code using convolutional neural network on MNIST dataset. Unfortunately, Keras prompts an error when going through the network. Your help is appreciated. I'd like to know the reason for such errors.

This is the error:  Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (45000, 28, 28)

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28, 1), padding= 'same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding= 'same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding= 'same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])
k = 4
num_val_samples = len(train_images) // k
num_epochs = 20
all_scores = []
for i in range(k):
    print('processing fold #', i)
    valid_data = train_images[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) *
                          num_val_samples] 
    valid_labels = train_labels[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) *
                                num_val_samples]
partial_train_images = np.concatenate(
    [train_images[:i * num_val_samples], train_images[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]], axis=0)
partial_train_labels = np.concatenate([train_labels[:i * num_val_samples], train_labels[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]],axis=0)

model.fit(partial_train_images, partial_train_labels,epochs=20, 
batch_size=1, verbose=0)
val_mse, val_mae = model.evaluate(val_data, val_targets, verbose=0)
all_scores.append(val_mae)
```

I've seen other pages, and none of the solutions there helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the channels dimension in your array, for grayscale images it should be a dimension with one element, so each sample is `(28, 28, 1)`:

```
partial_train_images = partial_train_images.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
val_data = val_data.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
```

Comment: It solved the previous issue, but there's a new error:                                                                         Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (45000, 10, 2, 2)

Comment: @Boogey_man Why do your labels have that shape? What is the task here?

Comment: The task is classification on the famous MNIST dataset. Honestly. I've no idea where the value 45000 has came from. Maybe, if I correct the input_shape value, it could work?

Comment: How are you loading the MNIST dataset?

Comment: From Keras through load.data method. If it could help, I can reference through the system files.

Comment: @Boogey_man You need to use keras.utils.to_categorical to y_train and y_test. You can refer this example https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py